# I can't log mysql server,when I try to login with root identity, even I input the correct password.(I am sure the password is correct 100%)

Tags: mysql

[image]

[image]

As the pictures showed `Access denied for user '-root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`,
but  I can connect MySQL server in Navicat premium, the password is the same as that in the command line.

Comment: Read the error message carefully: it's saying you're trying to log in as "-root" with a `-` on the front, not "root"; just remove that `-` from your command.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -u root -p
```

is the correct syntax

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you, please consider to mark it as answer